# Simplifying ViewModel properties in an MVVM design

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am new to MVVM, and I believe I have successfully built an MVVM app to appreciate it. I soon realised that I could not have properties like below to fire notifications:

```cs
public string Status { get; set; }
public bool IsIdle { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<SpecifiedRecord> FilesCollection { get; set; }
```

I had to rewrite them as below:

```cs
private string _status;
public string Status
{
    get { return _status; }
    set
    {
        _status = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Status));
    }
}

private bool _isIdle;
public bool IsIdle
{
    get { return _isIdle; }
    set
    {
        _isIdle = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsIdle));
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<SpecifiedRecord> filesColl = new ObservableCollection<SpecifiedRecord>();
public ObservableCollection<SpecifiedRecord> FilesCollection
{
    get { return filesColl; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.filesColl)
            filesColl = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilesCollection));
    }
}
```

MVVM has been there for nearly 9 years, and I thought in this day and age, Microsoft would allow OnPropertyChanged events to fire automatically i.e. built-in to Net without us having to write it everytime because if I find it very inefficient to do so.

Alternatively, is there a more simplified way to achieve the same by way of an inherited class?

Sources:
https://github.com/mainroads/SpecifiedRecordsExporter/blob/mvvm/SpecifiedRecordsExporter/MVVM/ViewModels/MainPageViewModel.cs
https://github.com/mainroads/SpecifiedRecordsExporter/blob/mvvm/SpecifiedRecordsExporter/MVVM/ViewModels/ViewModelBase.cs

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: There are source generators and code weavers for that... Also passing property name to OnPropertyChanged can be omitted with default value null and special attribute

Comment: "I thought in this day and age," - yeah there are a lot of things you'd think in this day and age Microsoft would do when it comes to frontend UI and .NET, yet here we are almost 20 years after the golden age of WPF and ASP.NET with no modern usable frontend frameworks from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` alot using the `CallerMemberName` attribute and using an `Inherited Class`

```
public class Core : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected void PropChanged([CallerMemberName] string callerName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(callerName));
    }
 }
```

Then you use it like so after adding `: Core` to your class

```
public class Program : Core
{
    private bool _isIdle;
    public bool IsIdle
    {
        get
        {
            return _isIdle;
        }

        set
        {
            //if (_isIdle != value)
            //{
                _isIdle = value;
                PropChanged();
            //} reduce number of events (comments)
        }
    }
}
```

You can also specify the `Caller Name` manually to trigger an update for a different property.

This is the [most modern way of doing this](https://github.com/HypsyNZ/Binance-Trader/blob/master/BinanceTrader/BVVM/Core.cs) that I know of, The extra bonus here is you can also use the `Core` class for anything `Static`

Comment: There are plenty of libraries like MvvmLight and MvvmCross that do exactly that already. No need to reinvent the wheel. Plus, you can also skip doing that entirely using the MVVM Source Generators.

Comment: There is a zero percent chance I will use a third party library for something I can do in 10 lines of code but someone might find your suggestions useful.

Comment: Also I haven't reinvented anything, I just followed the actual pattern, You can look at the link provided if you need more examples for WPF or MVVM

Comment: Those libraries offer so much more useful functionality, but it's obviously up to you to choose whichever way suits you best. I just mentioned this, because instead of only implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, as you suggested, those libraries also implement `INotifyPropertyChanging` and offer methods to set the new value only if it differs from the current value, reducing the amount of unnecessarily raised `PropertyChanged` events.

Comment: You could just check `value != property` in the setter to accomplish the same thing, `INotifyPropertyChanging` sounds interesting though, thanks.

Comment: I added an edit based on your comments

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Just keep in mind that `value != property` performs a value comparison on value types but a reference comparison on reference types and might cause problems when dealing with strings (due to locale/culture).

Answer (score 1):

There's no need anymore for all that boilerplate code.

Using the [Source Generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/overview) from the MVVM Community Toolkit you can inherit from `ObservableObject` and then write your properties like this:

```cs
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string name;
}
```

This will be used to generate a class that looks similar to this under the hood:

```cs
partial class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            if(name.Equals(value)) return;
            OnPropertyChanging();
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also raise notifications for other properties and have commands auto-generated, too:

```cs
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(FullName)]
    string firstName;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(FullName)]
    string lastName;

    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

    [RelayCommand]
    private void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {FullName}!");
    }
}
```

Note that the backing fields for auto-generated properties must be lowercase, because the generator will create the properties beginning with an uppercase letter.

Commands will have the same name as the method with the "Command" suffix, so `SayHello()` becomes `SayHelloCommand`. In case of an async method, e.g. `async Task SayHelloAsync()`, the Command will still be called `SayHelloCommmand`, without the "Async" suffix.

I've also written a [blog series](https://ewerspej.hashnode.dev/series/mvvm-goodness) going into more detail about this.

Comment: Thanks Julian, above is much appreciated, and I will certainly look through your blog series for more knowledge. For the scope I am achieving right now, I feel like attempts to simply with built-in methods would be sufficient for now.  

With third party toolkits, we have to abide by the implementation the third party toolkit came up with, and we may not agree with that implementation/look. For example,
 
The following should have been it, but hopefully one day! 

    [ObservableProperty]
    string FirstName {get; set;};

Comment: That would only be possible using IL Weaving. For that you could use Fody: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged. It doesn't offer as much functionality as the Source Generators of the MVVM Community Toolkit, though. Generally, you'll always need to use some kind of implementation or library as these things usually don't come built-in for good reason. Properties are a core feature of C# and are not only used in MVVM. Making them observable by default would come with a performance penalty for no reason.

Comment: @McoreD FYI, if your property name is supposed to be `FirstName`, then the Source Generators would still work for you, because `[ObservableProperty] string firstName;` (or `_firstName`, both work) will produce a property called `FirstName`.